# Как передать содержание формы в обработчик php?

Tags: jquery, ajax, php, javascript

Добрый день!

Такая у меня проблема. Я хочу реализовать предпросмотр описание. Само описание делается с помощью bbcode. [b],[i]... Как реализовать такой скрипт:

1. Данные передаются с `<textarea id='prosm' name='info'>` в php obr.php методом GET или POST.
2. Данные обрабатываются в php файле(Теги переводят с bbcode => html).
3. После чего возвращает данные и выводит в каком-то диве.

Хотелось реализовать в режиме онлайн. Т.е сразу пишем и оно преобразовывает и выводит нам ниже текст. Или можно было реализовать в по нажатию кнопки. Но самое гламное без перезагрузки. Я вот на php написал но жаль что язік работает на стороне сервера...

Помогите, пожалуйста!

Comment: Ребята помогите!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery

Когда пользователь уберет фокус с инпута, текст будет выведен в `<div id="dir-preview"></div>`.

```
$('#input id').focusout(function () {
    $('#div-preview').text($('#input_id').val());
});
```

Comment: а как через php его передать?